# Data Storage - which approach for a song-lyrics-app?

Tags: android, storage

I want to write an android app that basically shows titles of songs in a list view, and by selecting one song in the list, the lyrics of that sing are shown in a textview. In a second step there would be maybe a translation of the lyrics for every song.

So far nothing too complicated, but since I'm completely new to android programming, I wonder what's the best approach to store the data (i.e. the song titles/lyrics). I thought about a single (xml?)-file for each song where the filename is the title and the file contains the lyrics. I think that would make it easy to add new songs. where would such files be stored typically? /res/xml?

Or would another approach be more suitable? database storage? content provider?

Comment: Translating lyrics is close to impossible (unless you simply want to give people a hint of what the song's about). Just saying.

Comment: yeah, its probably not gonna be automatic translation, im thinking more of a manual translation that is also stored, since i would just need translation to 1 language...  but it's a pretty vague idea anyway

Comment: Even that would be a challenge though :) but sounds fun.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a database and a content provider since it becomes very trivial to bind the content to ListViews using the Loader API.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation about [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), you have several options.

But the storage strategy that seems to meet your needs is an **SQLite Database**.

You can make use of [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to get it working.

It will require quite an amount of work and understanding to implement it but it's worth the effort :

- Esier than other solutions to manipulate data once it stored.
- A lot of android component are designed to work with databases cursors.
- Easy to add new data and structures as your application evolves.
- You will learn a lot about how develop android apps "the right way".

If i were you i would **avoid** :

- [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) because this is not suited for list of data as there isn't any "id mechanism". On the other hand it is pretty easy to use for small settings.
- [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) because it is difficult to manipulate the data once it is stored. Also it is not the recommended way to store that type of data.